# Full page reload whenever I change category or product - Why?

Tags: magento-1.9

Instead of loading the relevant portion of the page,  the full page reloads when I change categories, product or any other part of the page.
This results in  bad browsing experience and eyes ache...
Any idea of how to prevent it?

Answer (score 1):

> Full page reload whenever I change category or product - Why?

Quick answer: because this is standard on the internet whenever you click a link.

> Any idea of how to prevent it?

Yes, you can implement AJAX requests/reloads for the parts where you don't want to reload the whole page.

Comment: Just to add to this Anna, making Magento all AJAXy has definitely been done before although I can't say I particularly liked it.

https://www.betabrand.com/

https://www.reddit.com/r/Magento/comments/33mcgq/we_did_it_we_converted_our_magento_site_to_a/